# Do I need to sanitize quickform inputs in a extension?

Tags: quickform

Hopefully this is a quick one. I'm creating a form in an extension. Regular QuickForm - nothing special. Do I need to sanitize the inputs before processing them? Or does Civi/QuickForm handle that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you saving the data? If you are using the api, then no there is no need to sanitize it, the api already guards against sql injection.

Comment: Yep, saving using the ppi. Great - thank you!